# xreplace in Drake Symbolic

Tags: drake

Currently drake offers the Substitute method to allowing the replacement of all occurrences of a variable in s with a corresponding expression in s. Is there a way to replace an expression in s with an expression in t (similar to Sympy [xreplace](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.xreplace))?

For example I would like to take transform:
$$ 2xyz sin(q) \rightarrow 2xyz \left(\frac{2t}{1+t**2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

I'm not surprised that no such function is built-in yet, but I was surprised to find that there doesn't appear to be any way to implement it for yourself given the available pydrake API.

I've filed https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16013 as feature request.

Once https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/16014 is merged, this (unittest) example will work:

```py
import pydrake.symbolic as sym
...

    def _xreplace(self, expr, rules):
        if isinstance(expr, float) or isinstance(expr, sym.Variable):
            return expr
        assert isinstance(expr, sym.Expression), expr
        for old, new in rules:
            if expr.EqualTo(old):
                return new
        ctor, old_args = expr.Deconstruct()
        new_args = [self._xreplace(e, rules) for e in old_args]
        return ctor(*new_args)

    def test_xreplace(self):
        x, y, z, q, t = [sym.Variable(ch) for ch in "xyzqt"]
        expr = 2*x*y*z*sym.sin(q)
        rules = [(sym.sin(q), (2*t) / (1+t**2))]
        new_expr = self._xreplace(expr, rules)
        self.assertEqual(
            str(new_expr),
            "(2 * x * y * z * ((2 * t) / (1 + pow(t, 2))))")
```